# How can I get the trace category from TraceListener?

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, tracelistener, semantic-logging

So I subclassed TraceListener in order to pipe output to EntLib6 SLAB without the need for injecting a customer logger implementation. The problem that I'm running into now is that I need to see that category that was provided with `Trace.Writeline(message, category)` and I'm not sure where that is. Where can I get the category from my custom TraceListener?

The end goal is really to get info from traces output in a library and send them through my actual logger in the application that consumes the library. I'm also open to any better techniques for this.

Comment: You mentioned TraceListener, if that is the Systems.Diagnostic one, then use the base the Essential Diagnostics uses. Then you have only 1 override and that gives you access to the TraceEventType https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Listeners&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

I followed examples from https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureTraceListeners

Basically in your custom tracelistener, when you override methods like
public override void WriteLine(string message, string category)

you get the category inside the method. you can pass it to your own handling method from there.